# How to custom ActionBar android with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat, navigationbar, appcompatactivity

I work with Xamarin Forms. My Android activity extends FormAppCompatActivity. I use a MasterDetailPage and this.Detail is init with new NavigationPage(new PagePerso()). I have a xamarin.forms.view and its renderer to Android.
I would like put this inside the NavigationBar (ActionBar to Android).
I tried to use a NavigationPageRender. Then I tried to use :

`protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e){
base.OnElementChanged(e);
Android.Views.View actionBar = base.ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
...}`

Thanks you in advance for your help !
If you have an other solution, suggest me ! (I use Xamarin forms, FormAppCompat, MasterDetailPage and NavigationPage to its Detail)

Solution and new problem :

I have finally come to add an Android.View inside ActionBar using ViewGroup. Now, my problem is that I want to add a custom view (xamarin) ...

`Android.Widget.Button bt = new Android.Widget.Button(base.ViewGroup.Context);
 ViewGroup actionBar = (ViewGroup) base.ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
 actionBar.AddView(viewGroup);`
The button with this code is added well.

So I have `MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView();`
And I would like add view as viewGroup previously but it's not an Android.Views.View.

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `actionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`?

I have recently seen some inconsitencies with this approach using AppCompat that I'm about the report to Xamarin.